# Getting events in a button in a panel used as a Table cell

Tags: gwt, event-handling

I'm using GWT 1.6.

I am creating a panel that contains a Button and a Label, which I then add to a FlexTable as one of its cells.

The Button is not receiving any Click events. I see that the table supports determining which Cell is clicked on, but in this case, I want the Mouse events to propagate to the various widgets inside the cell. Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I hit that, too - no widgets in the table will receive events.  I ended up using code like this:

```
FixedWidthGrid dataTable = createDataTable();
...
dataTable.addTableListener(new TableListener() {

    public void onCellClicked(SourcesTableEvents sender, int row, int cell) {
        storyViewer.showStory(table.getRowValue(row));
    }

});
```

You could probably start with something like that, then programmatically send events to your button widget to make the appearance of clicking.

Comment: Ultimately there will be more than one clickable widget in the cell. What I am trying to implement is a table header, that has a button to sort and another button to set a filter. So I have to know which of the Widgets the user was actually clicking on within the cell.

Comment: Hmmm.  So, you'll need to know the location of the click.  Not sure that's there - it might be.  BTW - are you using a FixedWidthGrid?  It has support for sorting.

Comment: I've never seen a FixedWidthGrid -- I assume its in some third-party library?

Comment: It's from gwt-incubator.  Sorry, I just realized you said you're using FlexTable.  Try adding a clickhandler, then debug to see what you get in the event.  Maybe there's something useful there.

Comment: I have to say I'm using anchors, images, and markers (gwt-google-maps) in a FlexTable and they have no problems getting events.  Either the listeners aren't being added correctly to the widgets or something is erroneously canceling propagation.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how big your table will be use a Grid instead.  All of your widgets will receive there events.  I have done this and created my own sortable table.

Comment: Also one other thing.  Where does it state that widgets within a FlexTable will not receive events?  Maybe your not adding handlers for your widgets?

Answer (score 0):

You have to subclass the Button google Class and add a constructor with two additional arguments (int col, int row).
e.g.

```
public class RuleButton extends Button {

 private int row;
 private int col;

 public RuleButton(String html, ClickListener listener, int row, int col) {
  super(html, listener);
  setRow(row);
                setCol(col);
 }
        // getters and setters for row and col attributes.
}
```

When adding the button, call this constructor and pass row and col indexes to it.